# Printf for float in c

Tags: c, atmel

I'm actually trying to print a float in c using atmel std and instead of printing the value , it gives me just "f". Anyone knows why it's like this?

code :

```
  float dist = 2.0*3.14*0.25*count;

  printf("counter : %d\n",count);
  printf("dist : %f\n", dist);
```

so, counter's actually a volatile long that updates after a button click on my hardware, consider it's working, the print of it's correct, but the print of dist's not correct, it gives me this:

```
dist : f
counter : 12
dist : f
counter : 12
dist : f
counter : 12
dist : f
counter : 12
dist : f
counter : 12
dist : f
```

Even if i try printing 0.25 like:

```
printf("%f\n",0.25);
```

it gives me the output "f"
[here 's the compiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8t4e.png)

Tested this, but it didn't worked:

```
    char b[10];

    uint32_t dist = b_radious*counter*M_PI*2.0f;

    dist = (dist + 1) >> 1;

    unsigned units = dist/1000;
    unsigned fraction = dist - (dist*1000);

    sprintf(b, "%4u.%03u", units, fraction);
```

Comment: it seems a problem with the toolchain? which compiler are you using?

Comment: Aside: if you have `long count;` then you need `%ld` format specifier.

Comment: Check your GCC compiler as for me it is giving correct output.

Comment: but the dist value is a float return since it have float multiplying the counter wich's a long. if i try printing ld instead of f, it gives me a int number

Comment: and i'm using the atmelstudio to compile the code, it's a software to use in embedded computing (ATSAME7000)

Comment: probably the processor you are using does not have floating point support in it and is using soft floating point. Try compiling the program with the -msoft-float flag on gcc

Comment: That is not what I meant: you should use `printf("counter : %ld\n",count);` instead of `printf("counter : %d\n",count);`. it was an *aside*.

Comment: oooo sure, thaks

Comment: and if i make a casting on the float variable, it just prints me the int value, like

Comment: int ival = (int) dist;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for `printf` to support floating-point output, it would need to include a rather substantial amount (thousands of bytes) of code which would be totally useless for many applications that use printf but don't use it to output floating-point numbers.  Some tool chains will attempt to automatically link in a full-featured version of `printf` if code outputs floating-point numbers, and a minimal one if it doesn't, but some tool chains require that the user manually select which version of `printf` to use.

Note that if code space is of any concern, using constructs like:

```
/* Output a number from 0.000 to 9999.000 */
uint32_t xi = x*2000.0f;
xi = (xi+1) >> 1; // Round value without extra floating-point math
unsigned units = xi/1000;
unsigned frac = xi - (units*1000);
sprintf(out, "%4u.%03u", units, frac);
```

and avoiding the use of floating-point formats with `printf` may avoid the need to use the larger `printf` library, while using far less code space than that library would consume.

Comment: check the edit to see what i've tested, but it didn't worked

Comment: output: nÇ@ Ÿ@nÇ@ Ÿ@

Comment: I assume you're then outputting `b` somehow?  If you want to use `printf` instead of `sprintf`, get rid of the `out` argument.  As an embedded programmer, I'm more prone to use `sprintf` rather than `printf` so as to allow data to be output to e.g. an LCD display or other device that wouldn't really work with `printf`.

Comment: yes, i'm using it to print on a lcd, i'm just using printf to debug since when i put the sprintf and use my function to draw it on the lcd, the RTT stops working.

Comment: If you want to output values with three significant figures, you need to multiply by 2000.0f, not 2.0f.  What happens if you try to do something like `printf("%4u.%03u", 1234,56);`?  How about `printf("%4d.%03d", 1234,56);`  Different lightweight versions of `printf` include different features.  If you're trying to use a typical text based LCD, a useful trick is to output integers right to left, by repeatedly computing `x%10` and `x/10`, inserting a decimal point after outputting some number of digits.

Comment: dude you really helped me, thanks a lot. it worked!!

Comment: @gnites: So what did you end up doing?

Comment: @gnites I notice that your floating point values posted seem to be a crude value for π (which might as well be `22 / 7` and `0.25` which could be `/4`. It's often possible to avoid floating point altogether.

Comment: used sprintf, i checked that a flag in rtt was always setting 0 after doing the print in lcd, so I changed the flag to !flag and used your method to print on lcd . Only isue now's that lcd screen have some noise in the right side.

Answer (score 0):

On embedded systems, it's common to have a printf/snprintf that does not handle float, only int. This is code that prints a float using a snprintf that only prints ints; the code also avoids use of double. It all adds up in saving a few kbytes flash.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
   convert a floating-point number to a string.
   uses integer-only snprintf.
   uses float, not double.
   output is in engineering notation.
*/

static const float pwr10[] = {1e36,  1e33,  1e30,  1e27,  1e24,  1e21,  1e18,
                              1e15,  1e12,  1e9,   1e6,   1e3,   1e0,   1e-3,
                              1e-6,  1e-9,  1e-12, 1e-15, 1e-18, 1e-21, 1e-24,
                              1e-27, 1e-30, 1e-33, 1e-36};

void ftoa(float f, char *buf, size_t bufsiz) {
  char sign[2] = {0};
  uint32_t p;

  if (f < 0) {
    f = -f;
    sign[0] = '-';
  }

  if (f == 0)
    p = 12;
  else
    for (p = 0; p < sizeof(pwr10) / sizeof(pwr10[0]) - 1; p++)
      if (f >= pwr10[p])
        break;
  uint32_t exponent = 36 - 3 * p;
  float mantissa = f / pwr10[p];

  mantissa += 0.00005; // 4 digit precision
  uint32_t digits = mantissa;
  uint32_t fraction = (mantissa - digits) * 10000.0;
  snprintf(buf, bufsiz, "%s%d.%04de%d", sign, digits, fraction, exponent);
}

void main() {
  char fbuf[16];
  float f = 0;
  printf(">");
  while (scanf("%f", &f) != EOF) {
    ftoa(f, fbuf, sizeof(fbuf));
    printf("%s\n>", fbuf);
  }
}
```